# Convert type string to type checksum256

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, hash

fist off let me get this strait, yes I know the dangers of memo parsing, yes I am aware of the vulnerabilities that can be created from doing such a process, so please there is no need to lecture me about the things I am already aware of.

i'm doing some string parsing and need to convert a string value of a checksum256 to a checksum256 type;

so like

```
string hash_string = "a6f7b874ea69329372ad75353314d7bcacd8c0be365023dab195bcac015d6009";
```

to

```
checksum256 hash = <hash_string>;
```

I have found the other way around to make checksum256 into a string but not string to checksum256.

Comment: I see this can take up to a year to get an answer here. . .

Answer (score 1):

```
string hash_string = "a6f7b874ea69329372ad75353314d7bcacd8c0be365023dab195bcac015d6009";

char hash_char_array[32] = ConvertHexStringToCharArray(); // You have to convert the Hex string to a 32-byte long char-array, which seems to be the biggest problem.

auto hash = eosio::checksum256::make_from_word_sequence<char>(hash_char_array[0], hash_char_array[1], ..., ..., hash_char_array[31]);
```

take a look [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/8150548265/), for a full example.